# How to hold previous opened form active in C#?

Tags: c#, winforms

I have two forms ,for example form1 and form2
the form1 is parent form ,from form1 im calling form2 and show it ,but the problem is when second form "form2" has been opened the previous form will be inactive ?
Please tell me how to have multiple form active at same time.

Comment: Looks like you're forming form form1 from form form2 which is wrong you should form form form2 from form form1.

Answer (score 2):

You probably want to use `Form.Show()` instead of `Form.ShowDialog()`. The first one will show a form along side anther one while the other will "pause" the first form until you close the 2nd one.

Answer (score 2):

Use

```
Form.Show()
```

Instead of

```
Form.ShowDialog()
```

Answer (score 2):

set TopMost property of form2 to true
and then use form2.Show() instead of ShowDialog()

OR
you can open form 2 in another thread like what i done

```
    private void ShowForm2()
        {
            new Form2().ShowDialog();
        }


        private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            System.Threading.Thread th = new System.Threading.Thread(new System.Threading.ThreadStart(ShowForm2));
            th.Start();
        }
```

Comment: Note that using another thread for the 2nd `Form` will require some additional care if the 2 forms are gonna interact with each other.

Comment: Yes,thats true i showed possible solution and i think the first solution (setting TopMost property to true) is better

Answer (score 1):

How are you showing your 2nd form? Sounds like you're showing it in a modal way - you don't want to!

Answer (score 0):

Copy and paste this code into your second form class:

```
    protected override bool ShowWithoutActivation {
        get {
            return true;
        }
    }
```